# Pass checkbox values to database by using codeigniter and that time Error Occured

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
Parsing Error
Message: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'
Filename: models/Register_model.php
Line Number: 23
```

---

```
$skills = $this->input->post('skills[]');
$data = array(
  'skills' => implode(",", $skills); line nos:23
);  

$insert_id=$this->db->insert("regi_user",$data);  
return $insert_id;
```

Comment: First fix your syntax error. Then we can try to help you getting the checkbox value (which is a boolean I guess) into the database.

Comment: please explain any example wise

Comment: Your code has a syntax error, that means that your code isn't even running. Like the error said `Message: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'`. You got an error on line 23.

Comment: Delete the trailing semicolon on line 23, that's your syntax error.

Comment: Thank you @Blacksilver.Finaly I got the answer.